# How to rewrite urls to get slug in view

Tags: django, django-urls

**Django 3.0.7**

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:categories>/', include(('categories.urls', "categories"), namespace="categories")),
]
```

**categories/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CategoryView.as_view(), name='list'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoryView(ListView):

    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["object_list"] = context["object_list"].filter(category__slug="linux") # Hardcoded so far
        return context

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["categories/post_list.html"]
```

Then I request http://localhost:8000/linux/

**Problem**

In the request that arrived kwargs is empty.

Why does this happen and how can I cope with this?

Comment: What do you see when you access that page? I'm not sure why you've declared your include this way: `include(('categories.urls', "categories"), namespace="categories"))` I think just `include("categories.urls", namespace="categories")` is enough.

Comment: Your variant of inclusion causes: "Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead".

But anyway, include is working. If I'm not mistaken, the problem is not in the include. The interpreter stops at a breakpoint in the view. So, include is working. But catching angle bracketed param  is the problem.

Comment: Usually, you would add `app_name = 'categories'` in `categories/urls.py`, then use `include('categories.urls')` without setting `namespace` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`self.kwargs['categories']`** to get the slug value from URL.

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["object_list"] = context["object_list"].filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['categories'])
        return context

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["categories/post_list.html"]
```

But, If I had a choice, I would have override the **`get_queryset(...)`** method instead of `get_context_data(...)`, which is more Django way in this case

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['categories'])

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["categories/post_list.html"]
```